# Boost.Python throws exception while printing traceback

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, boost, traceback

Environment: Python 3.5 and Boost 1.61.

I have a function that prints the python traceback. It relies on the following mechanism:

```python
traceback.format_exception(exType, value, traceBack);
```

This is the function itself:

```cpp
std::string pythonTraceBack()
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    PyObject* exType;
    PyObject* value;
    PyObject* traceBack;
    PyErr_Fetch(&exType, &value, &traceBack);
    object oExType(handle<>(borrowed(exType)));
    object oValue(handle<>(borrowed(value)));
    object oTraceBack(handle<>(borrowed(traceBack)));
    // 1.
    object lines = import("traceback").attr("format_exception")(oExType, oValue, oTraceBack);
    std::string result;
    for (int i = 0; i < len(lines); ++i)
        result += extract<std::string>(lines[i])();
    // 2.
    PyErr_Restore(exType, value, traceBack);
    return result;
}
```

1. This line seems to be causing the problem. Replacing it with

```cpp
object lines = import("traceback").attr("format_exc")();
```

seems to solve the problem but the output is not a traceback.

2. I tried commenting out this line and nothing changed.

I have also tried replacing `oExType, oValue, oTraceBack` with their corresponding raw objects `exType, value, traceBack`, but that causes conversion errors during compilation.

Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

std::string pythonTraceBack() { /* ... */ }

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    Py_Initialize();

    try
    {
        object main_module = import("__main__");
        object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");

        object ignored = exec("print(1/0)", main_namespace);
    }
    catch (error_already_set const& e)
    {
        std::string error = pythonTraceBack();
        std::cout << "Traceback: " << std::endl << error;
    }

    // Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it would be better to include a [mcve]

Comment: `extractException()` given [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/EmbeddingPython) seems to work. Your code is missing a call to`PyErr_NormalizeException`.

Comment: @J.J.Hakala Thanks. It fixed my problem after I added `PyErr_NormalizeException` right after `PyErr_Fetch`.